# Set up authoritative DNS server

Tags: reverse-dns

I am trying to set up a hosting company. The hosting company is going to have a client with the domain widgets.de

The name of my company is hostingcompany.de. The name servers I am setting up are called ns1.hostingcompany.de and ns2.hostingcompany.de

In the zone file for widgets.de, I have

```
NS ns1.hostingcompany.de.
NS ns2.hostingcompany.de.
```

In the zone file for hostingcompany.de, I have

```
hostingcompany.de  300 IN NS ns-110.awsdns-13.com
hostingcompany.de  300 IN NS ns-1130.awsdns-15.com
ns1.hostingcompany.de. 300 IN A  34.65.125.52
ns2.hostingcompany.de. 300 IN A  52.43.124.76
```

Also, I created two more hosted zones per Amazon's [guidance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-reverse-dns/)

```
124.43.52.in-addr.arpa. 
      NS ns-2035.awsdns-62.co.uk.
      SOA ns-2035.awsdns-62.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
  34  PTR ns1.hostingcompany.de
```

and

```
76.124.43.in-addr.arpa. 
         NS ns-799.awsdns-35.net.
         SOA ns-2435.awsdns-62.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
      52 PTR ns2.hostingcompany.de
```

However, this is not working. When I try to submit these zone files, RIPE rejects them saying that ns1.hostingcompany.de and ns2.hostingcompany.de **do not exist as objects**. I think I have to do something with PTR records, but I don't know what.

Comment: If ns1 and ns2 are authorative, why are you declaring route53 as the authoritative nameserver for your domain?

Comment: Uhh.  Long pause.  So I tried with 
  hostingcompany.de 300 IN NS  ns1.hostingcompany.de
  ns1.hostingcompany.de 300 IN A 34.65.125.52, but that was even worse.

Comment: The answer to your question is:  I have no idea.  Maybe because Amazon's guidance said to?

Comment: Are you trying to use route53 for the reverse lookup zones? If so why are you hosting the reverse lookup zones separately?

Comment: I am trying to follow Amazon's guidance.  They say to create separate hosted zones for the pointer records.  There is a link in my question.  Yes, I am using Route 53 for everything.

Comment: At least part of the problem is in the DNS records for ns1.hostingcompany.de. Is it an A record or a CNAME?

Comment: It is an A record.  Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/830972/add-a-name-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PTR records are usually necessary if you are running a DNS or SMTP server to provide some proof that you are legitimate.  I found [this article](http://aplawrence.com/Blog/B961.html) to be quite illuminating.

I think the answer to this question is found towards the bottom of the link in the question.  You have to fill out a [form](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) and AWS will create the PTR record for you.  Creating a hosted zone in Route 53 for the pointer record does not appear to have any effect.  Nothing in the RFC prohibits the owner of the public IP address from allowing a customer to create a PTR record for that public IP address. Although AWS could allow customers to create PTR records for their Elastic IP addresses, they do not.

There are a lot of articles discussing how you need to create your own hosted zones for the PTR records, such as but not limited to Amazon's own article the question linked to.  You can definitely do this for private IP addresses if you are running a DNS server for a private network.  However, if you are running a publicly available DNS or SMTP server on a public IP address, more vetting is required.

In order to verify that the records are set up correctly, you have to get an answer to:

```
dig -x 34.65.125.52  (must answer ns1.hostingcompany.de)
```

Unless you do this, the TLD registrar will not accept your nameserver, and your SMTP mail will probably be rejected as spam.

In addition to the above, another problem was that these lines should also be included in the zone file for hostingcompany.de

```
hostingcompany.de. 300 IN NS ns1.hostingcompany.de.
hostingcompany.de. 300 IN NS ns2.hostingcompany.de.
```

It is still unclear to me why the top level domain requires that the domains own nameservers are listed as being nameservers for its own domain, but this does appear to be a requirement for some top-level domains.  After correcting the above problems, everything works.

I spent a long time trying to track down the above problems, and it did not seem to be documented anywhere, so I hope this helps someone.  I also found [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912) to be quite interesting and informative.  It is always good to read stuff written by the authorities.